# Summary of multi-configuration project

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to have a summary of all the builds in a multi-configuration project, so that I can see a trend in

- # of builds that succeeded
- # of builds that did not run
- # of builds that failed

Both textually (in a table) and graphically?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a system Groovy Script run via [Groovy Script Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin). Such a script has direct access to Jenkins via its [programming API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/). You'll need to write a new auxiliary job that analyzes other Matrix jobs, though. I do not think you can do it from within the job itself.

In order to see results graphically you can output them in jUnit format (as if they were tests) and use *Publish JUnit test result report* post-build step (again, this is done in the auxiliary job).